# migrate the custom feature dijit.Calendar into dijit.form.DateTextBox

Tags: calendar, dojo

I have a flat Calendar which can highlight the holidays & events.

It will get the stat (selected month) for calendar rendering when the calendar change month.

```
MyCalendar2._setCurrentFocusAttrOld = MyCalendar2._setCurrentFocusAttr;
MyCalendar2._setCurrentFocusAttr = function(d) {
    //Loading the new month monthStat via the UI / KB / SelectBox
    var cbFunc = function(){    MyCalendar2._setCurrentFocusAttrOld(d); };
    getMonthlyStat( dateStr(d), cbFunc);
}
```

My problem here: how can I implement this feature into the DateTextBox ??

Aims: the DateTextBox can highlight the holidays, auto fetch the holiday when changing month.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/allenchak/W4ze7/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dijit/form/DateTextBox` allows you to indicate a custom class to use for its popup calendar.  So if you were to change your code around to actually create an extension of `dijit/Calendar`, you could then pass that to `popupClass` on a `DateTextBox` instance.

Here's how you might minimally rearrange some of your code into an extension:

```
var CustomCalendar = declare(Calendar, {
    getClassForDate: function(d) {
        //mark the cell in different color to present tight
        var ds = dateStr(d);
        if( !isEmptyStr(calData[ds]) )
            return 'mystyle_' + calData[ds];
    },

    _setCurrentFocusAttr: function(d) {
        var self = this,
            args = arguments;

        getMonthlyStat(dateStr(d), function(){
            self.inherited(args);
        });
    }
});
```

Then to instantiate a `DateTextBox` that uses it:

```
var textbox = new DateTextBox({
    popupClass: CustomCalendar,
    constraints: constraints
}, "textbox");
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W4ze7/2/

You could also consider moving your utility functions into the extension, following the convention of prefixing their names with underscores to indicate that they're for internal use.